# Angular: get updated records after comment added

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, front-end-optimization

I have a post section in which user can add comments and reply. I have applied pagination logic to post section. When page loads initial 5 records of first page, I am displaying. Then I have reload button, on its click next 5 records of second page gets fetched from api and appended (`concat` used) to previous result like wise happens. I am calling `getallpost` function every time when reload button hits, when comment/reply gets added to get updated entries/data from api.

`getallpost` function.

```
getallpost() {
    this.formData = new FormData();
    this.formData.append("page", this.pageNumber);
    this.formData.append("perpage", this.perPageRecords);
    this.postService.getAllEventsPost(this.formData).subscribe((result) => {
     
        if (result['status'] === false) {
         
        } else {
          this.totalRecords = result.data.pagination.totalRecords;
          this.lastPage = result.data.pagination.LastPage;
          this.selectedpost = this.selectedpost.concat((result as any).data.data);
          this.selectedpost.map((item) => {
            item.show = false;
            item.isReadMore = true;
            item.isShow = true;
           
          });
        
        }
      
      });
  }
```

`pageNumber = 1` ,  `perPageRecords = 5` , `selectedpost = []` are defined.

on Relaod button click function is as follows.

```
 onReloadbuttonClick() {
    this.pageNumber++;
    this.getallpost();
  }
```

When comment/reply gets added function is like below

```
 onSubmit(post_id) {
    this.loading = true;
    if (this.f.comment.value) {
      this.postService
        .addPostComment(this.id, post_id, this.f.comment.value)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          if (data['message'] === 'Token is Expired') {
            this.loading = false;
            this.authService.logout();
          } else {
            if (data['status'] === false) {
              if (data['errors']) {
                console.log(data['errors'][0].comment);
              }
              this.loading = false;
            } else {
              this.form.reset();
              this.getallpost();
           
              this.notifyService.showSuccess(
                'Comment added successfully!!',
                ''
              );
              this.loading = false;
            }
          }
        });
    } else {
      this.notifyService.showWarning('Please enter the comment.', '');
      this.loading = false;
      return;
    }
  }
```

Reload button works as expected. The problem I am facing is when I add comment/reply it gets added  and success message gets displayed. But the comment I added not gets shown at that point even if I am calling `getallpost` function.

Its because of   `this.selectedpost = this.selectedpost.concat((result as any).data.data);` this line current page number value new updated data gets fetched and appended again and not get replaced with new updated data. Means e.g. initially there are 5 records of first page fetched. After comment added to one of the post then `getallpost` function gets called and 5 records of first page gets called again having respective updated post with comment added. **Ideally** only data should get updated and should not get appended.

Which logic should I apply to get updated records in `this.selectedpost` after comment/reply added in above case **without** reloading/refreshing page (like without using `location.reload` etc)?

I have tried some logics but those are not working as expected with reload button.

Please guide and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your problem statement properly or not.

Let me know if something is not making sense.

> `new updated data gets fetched and appended again and not get replaced with new updated data.`

Just set `selectedpost = []` each time you click on reload or before calling `getAllPost()` or inside of `getAllPost()` before assigning.

> `Which logic should I apply to get updated records in this.selectedpost after comment/reply added in above case without reloading/refreshing page`

Call `getAllPost` inside `onSubmit` after successful addition of comment to avoid `reload/refresh`

```
         } else {
          this.form.reset();
          this.getallpost(); // You are already doing this.
       
          this.notifyService.showSuccess(
            'Comment added successfully!!',
            ''
          );
```

There will be a delay obviously in getting updated details from DB using API. Hence you can show the spinner at the comment section level and populate as soon as you get the details.

I am assuming your API returns a proper response after adding comments.

Comment: If I set `selectedpost = [] ` on reload or in `getallpost()` function that will not serve the purpose of appending the result of pages to previous when reload hits. I have used concat to append first page posts to next page and that appended result will show on page. Yes, I have added function `getallpost()` to avoid reload/refresh but that call appending result of `this.pageNumber` whatever at that moment with comment added result, to previous `this.selectedpost` . This will resulting duplication of records

Comment: Still, your question is not clear. 

Ideally, the use case is to load the latest comments first. By, keeping this in my mind. here , is my solution.
set `selectedpost = []` like this then every time you get new (updated) results and even newly added comments as well with no duplication.

if `pageNumber` is causing the issue then try to reset according to reload or `getAllPost()`.